Spotfire - Flagging a process that is out of control
I have a data set with hundreds of jobs over a year time frame with the date it ran and the run time.
Each job has a run time and I'm trying to detect drifts when they occur by work week.
So if I have 4 consecutive weeks where the week median is above or below the overall median for the year I need to flag it. I created a week column and a median of run time by week over the job and week column and a flag column to highlight if that week's median run time was over the median. But as far as flagging if previous 4 weeks contain same flag for that job by unique work week I cant figure out.
Sample Data Set: (https://i.sstatic.net/DFRuS.png)
In the sample data set Job A had 4 consecutive weeks where the week's median was flagged as below, how would I flag this? Note that Job B did not have 4 consecutive weeks with the same flag, so I would not want to flag that job.
I need some value so that I can filter out of 100s of jobs to only show the ones that are flagging for the 4 consecutive week median having the same flag.
I was trying a unique count function but it would have to be over the Job and previous 4 weeks and flag. I don't think this function exists in spotfire.

This might work, but your sample data has very few weeks and no 'normal' rows.
First define a column that gives you the next week's flag, per job. Column [Next_Flag]
SN(First([Flag]) over (Intersect(Next([Week]),[Job])),[Flag])

SN(..) returns [Flag] when there is no week below.
Then define a column that tells you if there was a change going from one week to the next: the boolean result is turned into 0/1. Column [Flag_change]
integer([Next_Flag]!=[Flag])

Then count the changes over 4 weeks (current one and previous 3 weeks) to generate your alert:
case  
when (([Flag_change] + Sum([Flag_change]) over (Intersect(Previous([Week],3),[Job])))=0) and ([Flag]!='Normal') then 
 'Alert'
end

I added a clause in case the flag is equal to 'Normal'. You can change it to Flag is NULL if the Flag is null when normal.

In the Sum([Flag_change]) over (Intersect(Previous([Week],3),[Job])))=0) its only counting the 3rd week back and not the weeks in between. Could this be caused by the fact that I used  the YearAndWeek function to extract the week from the date column to use for [Week]? If so what would you recommend? Thanks again so much for your help.

It counts all weeks in my example. Can you provide an example of where it goes wrong?

So if you change week 5 for Job A to above it flags, It will flag no matter what for Job A in week 5 as long as week 2 has a flag change of 0, even if week 3 has a flag_change of 1 . I ran multiple different scenarios and It's only looking at the job_flag for the week-3 and not the weeks in between. I guess you could go the route of ([Flag_change] +Sum([Flag_change]) over (Intersect(Previous([Week],3),[Job])+Sum([Flag_change]) over (Intersect(Previous([Week],2),[Job])+Sum([Flag_change]) over (Intersect(Previous([Week],1),[Job])

Please provide one clear example as a dataset image.

https://imgur.com/a/JykqFII

Not sure if you can see the data set I attached but if you just change Job A for Week 3 to  above in the original data set you can see Job A in week 5 will still have an alert even though it should not.

You asked: "if I have 4 consecutive weeks where the week median is above or below the overall median for the year I need to flag it. ". But you do not want an alert if it goes from Above to Below, even though they are both abnormal. Please clarify what your goals are.

Sorry to clarify 4 of the same points, so 4 consecutive weeks above median or 4 weeks below median.
